# Issue: Ford ecosport 1 ltr ecoboost

Tags: ford, turbocharger

When engine starts it runs ok even when accelerating.

After 5-10 kms run it starts hesitating/misfiring while accelerating above 40 km/h, if accelerator released and pressed again it almost solves the issue.

Then when crusing at constant speed say at 100 km/h it runs smooth.

Spark plugs and coils replaced still issue not solved. Please help what could be the issue.

Obd scanner o2 sensor usually lies between 0.1 to .9 but while accelerating and leaving the accelerator it goes to 0.04 to 0.02 for 2-3 seconds then comes back to normal.

Also at idling maf sensor reading is 1.5 to 1.8 is it okay?